# NullPointerException on primitive boolean property

Tags: java, android, ironsource

I am trying to fix a bug that crash an app that I published to the Google Play store.

The crash stack trace from the Google Play console:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.myApp.Advertising.InterstitialAdsRunCallback.setViewed (InterstitialAdsRunCallback.java:11)
  at com.myApp.AndroidLauncher$2.onInterstitialAdClosed (AndroidLauncher.java:65)
  at com.ironsource.mediationsdk.A$4.run (A.java:7)
  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback (Handler.java:938)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:99)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:223)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:7888)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:592)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:981)
```

The code for the setViewed function is:

```
package com.myApp.Advertising;

public abstract class InterstitialAdsRunCallback implements Runnable {
    boolean viewed;

    public boolean viewedAd() {
        return viewed;
    }

    public void setViewed(boolean viewed) {
        this.viewed = viewed; // line 11
    }
}
```

And the code that is calling setViewed:

```
public void onInterstitialAdClosed() {
    InterstitialAdsRunCallback adRunnable = showInterstitialAdRunnable.getAdRunnable();
    adRunnable.setViewed(true); // line 65
    adRunnable.run();
    IronSource.loadInterstitial();
}
```

Decompiled InterstitialAdsRunCallback class from the .aab:

```
.class public abstract Lcom/myApp/Advertising/InterstitialAdsRunCallback;
.super Ljava/lang/Object;
.source "InterstitialAdsRunCallback.java"

# interfaces
.implements Ljava/lang/Runnable;


# instance fields
.field public viewed:Z


# direct methods
.method public constructor <init>()V
    .registers 1

    .line 3
    invoke-direct {p0}, Ljava/lang/Object;-><init>()V

    return-void
.end method
```

So, how is a primitive boolean property causing a NullPointerException? I'm probably missing something else.

Comment: The code as shown doesn't seem to be able to cause a NullPointerException, which suggests that there might be some compile-time or runtime modification of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R8, ProGuard and other similar optimization tools usually inline accessor methods but the line number information still points to the original source.

If `adRunnable` is null and the `setViewed()` accessor is inlined, you'll get an NPE like this.

Answer (score 0):

I think you cann't use the function `setViewed()` becouse `adRunnable` object is null not becouse the primitive boolean property ...

```
 java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.myApp.Advertising.InterstitialAdsRunCallback.setViewed
```

Check what the return of the function `showInterstitialAdRunnable.getAdRunnable();` is it null or not?

Answer (score -2):

You **cannot instantiate** abstract class directly, probably for this reason you're getting NullPointerException.

Comment: `You cannot instantiate abstract class directly` this will give a compile time error, not runtime, right ? meaning that OP wouldn't even have an app to put on the store if that were the case ?